# fmi2_import_get_variable_has_start(fmi2_import_variable_t*) API is always returning zero for Outputs and Global Block Outputs, is it expected behavior

Tags: fmi

I have a requirement of passing start value for Outputs and Global Block Outputs variables in FMI2.0.
As part of this , I am trying to utilize fmi2_import_get_variable_has_start(fmi2_import_variable_t*) API to check if the variable contains start. But unfortunately, above mentioned API is returning zero (0), so I could not proceed further for retrieving the start value.

My question is, is it expected behavior for fmi2_import_get_variable_has_start(fmi2_import_variable_t*) API not to read start value for Outputs and Global Block Outputs variables. Though I am getting 1 while trying to read from Parameters and Inputs variable.

I tried to call fmi2_import_get_variable_has_start(fmi2_import_variable_t*) API to make sure the above mentioned variables contain start value, so that the value can be retrieved later for further usage.
I was expecting to get a return value of 1 but the API is returning 0, resulting I am unable to retrieve the start value for Outputs and Global Block Outputs variable.